# Brute force recursive sudoku algorithm in C not ending

Tags: c, recursion

Please note that I have looked at several other posts, but none of them seem to answer my questions. The following piece of code is an attempt to make a brute force recursive algorithm, which takes in as parameters a two-dimensional array (representing a Sudoku puzzle) and a pointer which in this case points to the first element of the whole board. I should also mention that I have tested all of the functions present in this code, so please assume that they work perfectly.

To clarify, this is where I call the function in the `main.c` file:

```
  int *node = &board[0][0];
  solve(board, node);
```

And this is the code that should solve the Sudoku puzzle:

```
int* solve(int board[9][9], int *node) {
    int *lastNode = &board[9][9];

    if (node > lastNode) {
        int result = isSolved(board);

        if (result) {
            printBoard(board); 
            node = NULL;
            return node;
        } 
        return node - 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (empty(node)) {
            *node = i;
            node = solve(board, node + 1);

            if (node == NULL) {return node;}
        }
        else {node = solve(board, node + 1);}
    }

    if (node == NULL) {return node;}
    else {return node - 1;}
}
```

The problem is that when I execute the program, nothing happens. Is this because the tree is too large? And wouldn't that result in a segmentation fault? I appreciate any advice.

EDIT: I have modified `int *lastNode = &board[9][9]` to `int *lastNode = &board[8][8]`, but I still have the same issue. I have also filled in 79 squares on the board, with two empty squares remaining, which would drastically reduce the amount of computation needed, but the issue still prevails.

Comment: Upon cursory inspection, it looks like you are trying all possible combinations of values. How many ways do you think there are to fill however many empty spaces there are with 9 numbers? If there are, say, 30 spaces filled in and 51 empty spaces, how big is 9^51? How long would a computer take to count that high by ones?

Comment: As for whether this would cause a segment fault, recursing 81 times uses 81 times the stack space of one call. That is not much. The fact a program takes a long time does not mean it takes a lot of space.

Comment: Are your sure this line is correct `int *lastNode = &board[9][9];`? If the `board` is defined as `int board[9][9]` in the caller, the last element is `board[8][8]`.

Comment: To speed it up, you will need to check for invalid partial solutions as soon as possible, not wait until the board is completely filled. Treat the value 0 as a "don't care" value when checking partial solutions. Also, focus the checking on the element that has just been filled in, i.e. only check the row, column and block containing the modified element.

Comment: You will also considerably reduce the search space by placing only the numbers that *can* fit in the row, column and block, and backtrack if there are none.

Comment: Consider this line `*node = i;`. First time around the node gets the digit 1. At what point will it get a 2?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Well, I'm assuming that it will get a 2 when the consecutive line `node = solve(board, node + 1);` receives its return value. And when that happens the loop will go to the next value (2) and recursively search for the next possible node combinations. At least that was my intention in the code.

Comment: "the loop will go to the next value" It will only go to 2 if the node is empty. You put 1 to it in the first iteration. At what point does it become empty again?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for the observation. I modified that by moving the if statement out of the for loop. And I also realized that I should be resetting `*node = 0`.